# Difference between && and no ref in return type

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a difference in behavior when the return type is explicitly declared rvalue vs no ref?  According to the example below, there doesn't seem to be any difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A(int x) : x_(x) {}

    A(A&&) = default;  // VC12 hasn't implemented default move
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

    vector<int> x_;
};

struct B{
    B(int x) : a_(x) {}
    A&& foo1() { return move(a_); }  // explicitly declared as rvalue
    A foo2() { return move(a_); }    // no ref
    A a_;
};

int main() {
    B b1(7);
    A a1 = b1.foo1();
    B b2(7);
    A a2 = b2.foo2();       
    cout << a1.x_.size() << ' ' << a2.x_.size() << endl;
    cout << b1.a_.x_.size() << ' ' << b2.a_.x_.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This example has been compiled by Ideone's C++14 compiler (not sure of the exact version, I suspect it's gnu 5.1) and VC12 (Visual Studio 2013).  The only minor difference is VC12 requires an explicit move implementation.

Edit: [A related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732090/difference-between-return-by-rvalue-ref-return-by-value-when-you-return-us?rq=1) said that the two function end up doing the same thing.  However, "in many cases it allows the compiler to perform copy elision and elide the calls to the move constructor of the returned type, as permitted by paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard".  "Copy elision allows the compiler to create the return value of the function directly in the object."

Question 1: Copy elision should still happen when move is explicitly called, right?

Question 2:
When move is explicitly called on a lvalue (so a required called), A&& and A means the same behavior.  When move is not explicitly called, meaning the compiler performs copy elision, A should be the only return type.  Combining the two scenario above, can I conclude that return type A&& is not useful and only adds confusion?

Comment: *Is there a difference in behavior when the return type is explicitly declared rvalue?* - as opposed to **what**?

Comment: @SergeyA no ref, see B::foo1 and B::foo2.

Comment: Do not get used to `return move(something)`. It is useless and applied implicit (See: copy elision, return value optimization, return value construction)

Comment: @DieterLücking Not in this case; `a_` is a data member, not a function local temporary, so there is no automatic move.

Comment: you should not move on a return, because a return is defined to be a move, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
A&& foo1() { return move(a_); }
A foo2() { return move(a_); }
```

- `foo1` returns a (rvalue) reference.
- `foo2` construct an object `A` with the move constructor.

Comment: Do you expect the two behave differently?  In this example, they behave the same.

Comment: @CandyChiu He already explained the two behave differently :) There's a move construction happening in the second case, and not in the first.

Comment: @Praetorian BUT there isn't a difference according to the example.  I even printed how many times the move constructor was called.

Comment: @CandyChiu You most likely won't see a difference in the number of move constructor calls because of copy elision. You can compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` on gcc to prevent copy elision. In any case, looks like you found a duplicate that answers your question.

Comment: @Praetorian I see, that's helpful.  I edited my question.  I still don't understand why the standard allow A&& as a return type.  Seems to me it only add confusion.